# How to restart computer using js

Tags: node.js, batch-file, restart

is it possible to restart computer using nodejs? I've searched whole day but I still have no idea how to do it or is it possible. Maybe I can make `restart.bat` and run it in my js program? I'm grateful for any piece of code, idea, recommendation or anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, there is no node feature to shutdown or restart the computer. However, node is able to run shell commands.

`shutdown -h now` is the command on linux.

You would use childprocess ([here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)) to shut it down on Windows.

What is the reason you are looking to shut it down? There may be more effective methods depending on situation and reason.

Comment: I'm making small quiz for my school project. In case you guess incorrectly, your computer will restart itself and you must start all over again. It's just for fun.

Comment: @Srki, that is not fun, it is potentially data destructive.

Comment: @Compo It's just for school project. I'll be running it on my laptop so if something happens it's all my fault.